# UCCSD in qiskit deprecated?

Tags: qiskit

Is this now deprecated or moved? I've been looking for it. It was in

```
from qiskit.chemistry.aqua_extensions.components.variational_forms import UCCSD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it wasn't removed, it's here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/master/qiskit/chemistry/components/variational_forms/uccsd.py

Comment: I thought qiskit-aqua is the old version. I don't see it at qiskit.aqua

Answer (score 1):

qiskit-aqua is the github repo in the link above. Chemistry is in the qiskit-aqua repo under qiskit.chemistry so

`from qiskit.chemistry.components.variational_forms import UCCSD`